# Vectorization and inner product of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inner-products

We know that the Frobenius inner product $A \cdot B = tr(A^\top B)$ between two $n\times n$ matrices  $A$ and $B$ can be represented as
$$ A \cdot B = \langle\vec A, \vec B\rangle  = tr \vec A (\vec B)^\top$$
where on the right side $\langle \cdot, \rangle$ is the ordinary Euclidean scalar product and where $\vec X$ denotes the vectorization of $X$. I am curious about (and would have use of) a slightly more general case.

In particular, I have matrices $Q,A,B$ where I want to use positive definite matrix $Q$ to "skew" the inner product, i.e., I am interest in the rewriting the quantity
$$
tr (Q A^\top  B)
$$ 
in terms of $\vec A$ and $\vec B$ as is possible when $Q=I$.

> My question is thus: Can we write
>   $$tr (QA^\top B) = \langle \vec A, \vec B \rangle_Q $$
>   where $\langle\cdot, \cdot \rangle_Q$ is a skewed euclidean inner product on $\mathbb{R} ^{n^2}$, depending on $Q$?

My guess would be that this is indeed possible and should look something like
$$tr (QA^\top B) = tr  \left( (I \otimes Q) (\vec A \otimes (\vec B)^\top))\right) $$
but I am certainly not sure and don't really know how to proceed.

I would very much appreciate help in finding a rewrite of the quantity $tr (QA^\top B)$which is similar to this.

---

Edit for clarity:

The question could be reformulated as: Is there a euclidean inner product $\langle , \rangle _Q$ weighted by some matrix (say $M=M(Q)$), such that $tr( QA^\top B) = \langle \vec A, \vec B\rangle_Q=\langle M(Q) \vec A,\vec B\rangle$? In the end what I am after is to express $tr QA^\top B$ in terms of the trace of the outer product of $\vec A$ and $\vec B$.

---

Progress Update:

I was able to find a reference ( https://www.ime.unicamp.br/~cnaber/Kronecker.pdf) online which states that

$$ tr (ABC ) =  (\vec A^\top)^\top (I\otimes B) \vec C$$

which is more or less equivalent to what I am asking. However, as the reference does include a proof, I would still like this to be resolved.

Comment: How do you mean skew? As in a prescribed weight for position of each element? If so, then I think this won't work but you will need to work in vectorized space. But maybe you are happy to only be able to skew different rows differently? Then I think it will work.

Comment: By skew I am referring to the premultplication by the matrix $Q$ in the trace.

Comment: Ok, you can for sure get something more general with $vec(A)^T Q vec(B)$, where $Q$ is big diagonal matrix with one diagonal entry per matrix entry in each $A$ and $B$ but maybe you don't need it. Yes Kronecker product with identity matrix shall also help you get what you want. I think there is a good wikipedia on it. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product#Matrix_equations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For ease of typing, let's use $A:B$ instead of $A\cdot B$ to denote the Frobenius inner product,

and $a$ instead of $\vec A$ to denote vectorization, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= {\rm Tr}(A^TB) = &{\rm Tr}(B^TA) = B:A \\
A:B &= a:b
 &({\rm Frobenius\,product\,notation})\\
A:B &= a^Tb
 &({\rm Matrix\,product\,notation})\\
}$$
Using this we can develop various expressions for
the following scalar quantity
$$\eqalign{
{\rm Tr}(QA^TB) 
 &= {\rm Tr}(A^TBQ) \\
 &= A:BQ \\
 &= {\rm vec}(A):{\rm vec}(IBQ) \\
 &= a:(Q^T\otimes I)\,b \\
 &= a^T(Q^T\otimes I)\,b \\
 &= b^T(Q\otimes I)\,a \\
}$$